# How to add network card driver to GRUB?

Tags: networking, wifi, grub

*Disclaimer: I'm a newb and I need step by step guide. Thanks!*

I have installed GRUB to a USB using [this guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631048/how-to-install-grub-to-empty-disk-from-ubuntu-livecd) and it boots to GRUB 2.02.
The problem is that the GRUB cannot detect my network card.
I tried GRUB> `net_ls_cards` and it will return nothing and `net_bootp` will return error saying that I don't have any network card.

I am assuming that I will need to add some kind of driver so that GRUB can detect my network card. How do I **add a network driver to GRUB**?

My network card according to `lspci`:

`01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)`

Comment: `installed GRUB to a USB` ... USB what? ... that's like eating a yellow apple and saying `i ate a yellow`

Comment: USB thumb drive yes but you know what I mean...

Comment: Booting from the network is quite an involved process you should not be attempting as a newcomer. What are you actually trying to achieve? The linked question is about installing Ubuntu. Please consider the easy way: Download an installation image from [ubuntu.com](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=20.04.1&architecture=amd64), copy the contents onto the USB thumb drive (formatted with FAT32, assuming EFI boot) and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Newbie no, I do not know what you mean ... I have a hard drive that is connected through a USB port ... I believe that there are some differences between a USB connected hard drive and a thumb drive

Comment: @jsotola Does GRUB treat USB HDD and USB thumb drive and different thing?

Comment: @Hermann Let's say my usb thumb drive is 32mb big, there is no hard drive lying around and I don't have money enough to buy a new drives :)

Comment: @newbie Fair point. If you have an optical drive, burn the ISO on a CD. As a last resort, you can copy the image onto the target disk, boot the setup, manually add a partition and then install onto the same disk (with the new partition becoming the root partition).

Comment: @Hermann Aw, snap! I don't have optical drive present nor do I have a HDD or SSD inside my PC. There are no CD or DVD to burn things onto either. bummer!

Comment: So you do not wish to install Ubuntu, but rather have a true disk-less boot over wireless network. The only software that might achieve this I know of is http://etherboot.org/wiki/wirelessboot. It only includes two drivers and your wifi adapter is not supported. Even if you managed to boot Ubuntu using this technique, the system would need gigabytes of RAM to be usable in a decent manner. I recommend trying http://tinycorelinux.net/downloads.html. It fits into that 32 MB thumb-drive of yours and is made for these kind of applications.